# How to choose reverse to an older version in npm versioning when using npm publish

Tags: npm

I am publishing this package. I want to publish it at an older version or better revert to an older version to publish it at. This way I don't have 5 versions that are just console logs of one or two things. This is not me trying to install a package off npm, rather publish a package to npm.

I kept patching and didn't really noticed that there was a lot of patches that did not need to happen. I need to go back to a certain version of my package: i.e. v1.0.13, but it already exists when I try to do something like

`npm version 1.0.13`

Is there a way I can override this?

Comment: There is no way to do this, to my knowledge. You can't erase or overwrite an already existing version on npm.

Answer (score -2):

I would uninstall then reinstall npm to the correct version without whichever patches you want.

Here's the command I found to uninstall:

```
npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional|--no-save]
```

Comment: Im not installing a package btw, this is an npm module I am creating and versioning myself..

Comment: If you have the old version of your package, then you should uninstall your current npm package then install the old one you want. Most package managers (npm included) check version number before installation.